# Best way to remove duplicated code in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring

What is the best way to simplify the class, which contains two methods doing almost similar work.

```
enum State 
{
    Processing, Stoped
}

public static void CheckState(State state, Element elem)
{
    if (elem.State == state)
        //some work
}

public static void CheckValue(int value, Element elem)
{
        if (elem.Value == value)
            //some work
}
```

So, object of Element class has two fields of different types. What is the best way to remove duplicated code?

Comment: Move the first occurrence into a method, then call the method instead of the second (and subsequent) occurrence(s).

Comment: @ChrisF, this methods are invoked independently, not one, then another. When command is of one type, CheckState invokes, another - CheckValue. 
The problem is that State and Value is of different types.

May be I can make one generic method with parameter T (and T will be the first argument of this method)

Comment: @MikhailPliskovsky - I was assuming that the code alluded to by `//some work` was the same and what you'd refactor, not necessarily the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a function in for the condition. Passing in the Element as I'm assuming you need it for processing.

```
public static void CheckAndProcess(Func<bool> CheckCondition, Element elem)
{
     if (CheckCondition())
     {
        //some work
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
CheckAndProcess(()=>(elem.State == state), elem);
CheckAndProcess(()=>(elem.Value == value), elem);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without anonymous functions, too:

```
public static void CheckElement(Element element, State state = null, int? value = null)
{
    if ((state != null && element.State == state) || (value != null && element.Value == value.Value))
    {
        //some work
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//for state
CheckElement(element, myState);
//or
//for value
CheckElement(element, value: myValue);
```